# NodeJs : Change the project structure when releasing

Tags: node.js

I currently have the following structure in my project:

```
package.json
readme.MD
...
packages
   |
   --> package1
   --> package2
   --> ...
```

I would like to move `package1, package2, ...` out of the `packages` folder in the published version of my repo:

```
package.json
readme.MD
...
package1
package2
...
```

Is there any way to specify it in my `package.json` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to rely on a script or a build tool for this. Take a look at [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/).

The easiest solution however is to simply write a script in the package.json that does exactly this. If you're on UNIX, then this should work:

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy:prepare": "mv ./packages/* ./",
},
```